# Should all questions with a "SYSLINUX" type error when booting from usb be merged into one?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

A user asked [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288807/syslinux-error-on-boot-ubuntu-13-04) about failing to boot from a live-usb installation of Ubuntu. I copy pasted his error message into google and it turned up several other questions with similar problems:

- [Can't get USB flash drive to boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153603/cant-get-usb-flash-drive-to-boot?lq=1)
- [SYSLINUX? Booting off a Live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72696/syslinux-booting-off-a-live-usb?lq=1)
- [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd?lq=1)
- [question about 12.10 32 bit syslinux 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 usb direct boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225888/question-about-12-10-32-bit-syslinux-4-06-edd-2012-10-23-usb-direct-boot?lq=1)
- [Installing Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop amd64 using bootable USB-stick failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287529/installing-ubuntu-13-04-desktop-amd64-using-bootable-usb-stick-failed?lq=1)

All these problems involve booting from a live usb to only be met with the following message:

```
SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H: Peter Anvin et al
```

For some of these users there is a flashing underscore after the message, for others there are addition lines of output before the flashing underscore. The fact that there are so many different questions with various answers is making it difficult to navigate askUbuntu for a solution to this problem (hence why I think this new user decided to ask a new question).

I propose that these questions be merged into a community wiki that addresses all known instances of the error. I doubt that the 6 questions listed are all the instances of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a **very good idea.** I stumbled across the same issue while trying to clear up unanswered (tagged installation) questions. This is what I found:

**Links with answers:**

[Wont boot from USB, stops at SYSLINUX copyright](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71655/wont-boot-from-usb-stops-at-syslinux-copyright)

[Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)

**Links without answers:**

[Ubuntu not loading from USB flash on HP netbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252275/ubuntu-not-loading-from-usb-flash-on-hp-netbook?rq=1)

[SYSLinux Error on boot, ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288807/syslinux-error-on-boot-ubuntu-13-04)

[Can't get USB flash drive to boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153603/cant-get-usb-flash-drive-to-boot?rq=1)

[SYSLINUX? Booting off a Live USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72696/syslinux-booting-off-a-live-usb?rq=1) originally appeared to be merged with another question without answers but it appears that this is being addressed by @Luis Alvarado as we speak